# Probability of a tetrahedron (die with 4 faces)?

Tags: probability, dice

I have been doing some questions from an exam review with no solution and I have no idea how to work this problem. I know that $Pr(A_1) = \frac{1}{2}$, $Pr(A_2) = \frac{1}{2}$, $Pr(A_3) = \frac{1}{2}$, $Pr(A_1 \cap A_2) = \frac{1}{4}$, $Pr(A_1 \cap A_3) = \frac{1}{4}$, $Pr(A_2 \cap A_3) = \frac{1}{4}$ but how do I use this information?

> Let's look at a tetrahedron (die with 4 faces). Each one of these faces has one of the bitstrings "110", "101", "011", "000".
>
> For k=1,2,3, define the event
>
> A<sub>k</sub> = "the bitstring written on the bottom face has 0 (zero) at position k" For example, if the bitstring at the bottom face is 101, then A<sub>1</sub> is false, A<sub>2</sub> is true, and A<sub>3</sub> is false.
>
> Are the events A<sub>1</sub>, A<sub>2</sub>, A<sub>3</sub> pairwise independent? Justify your answer.
>
> Are the events A<sub>1</sub>, A<sub>2</sub>, A<sub>3</sub> mutually independent? Justify your answer.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairwise_independence

Comment: In this link there's a link to the definition of mutual independence. This fully solves your question.

Comment: @Alex thats soo strange the example in your link is almost exactly the same question thanks

Comment: you are welcome

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/715555/15941) which is already on hold.

Answer (score 1):

Two events are independent exactly if $$
  \mathbb{P}(X \cap Y) = \mathbb{P}(X) \cdot \mathbb{P}(Y) \text{.}
$$

Since per your question, $\mathbb{P}(A_1) = \mathbb{P}(A_2) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $\mathbb{P}(A_1 \cap A_2) = \frac{1}{4}$, the requirement above is satisfied (because indeed $\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{4}$), and therefore $A_1$ and $A_2$ are independent.

For mutual independence, you need for events $E_1,\ldots,E_n$ that $$
  \mathbb{P}(X_1 \cap X_2 \cap \ldots X_m) = \mathbb{P}(X_1) \cdot \mathbb{P}(X_2) \cdot \ldots \cdot \mathbb{P}(X_m)
$$
for *every* selection of events $X_1,\ldots,X_m$ from $E_1,\ldots,E_n$.