# What is the last digit of $.....\Biggl(\biggl(\Bigl(\bigl((7)^7\bigr)^7\Bigr)^7\biggr)^7\Biggr)^7 ......$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

$2005$ $7's$ are used in the following number ,so what is its last digit   :

Number: $.....\Biggl(\biggl(\Bigl(\bigl((7)^7\bigr)^7\Bigr)^7\biggr)^7\Biggr)^7 ......$

As i mentioned in the introduction , this number is written using $2005$ times $7's$ and i want to find its last digit.

My work: Its last digit is wanted so i used $\mod(10)$.

After that i formed the expression into $\bigl((7)^{7^{2004}}\bigr)$ , then i decided to use Euler's totient function.

${7^{\phi(10)=4}\equiv 1 \ (mod10)}$

In the next step , i said that ${7^{4k}\equiv 1 \ (mod10)}$ and  i checked over $7^{2004}(mod4)$.Then ,I found that $7^{2004}(mod4)=1$

As a result ,  $\bigl((7)^{7^{2004}}\bigr) \equiv 7^1 (mod 10)=7$

My first question is that is my solution correct ?

Secondly , if my solution is not correct , can you help me to write the correct ?

Thirdly , if my solution is correct but it is long ,can you share any shortcut or beneficial information to make it elegant.

$EDIT$: I want to find its last digit and it is an exponential tower where $n=2005$

Comment: What is "first" decimal? Least significant digit (units place)? That's more commonly called the last digit.

Comment: Just to be clear:  is this the [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration) of $7$ $2005$ times (written $^{2005}7$)?  And do you mean the ones digit?

Comment: @Deepak , yeah the last digit.Sorry for my english

Comment: I don't think you're using the correct order of operations for a tetration: $^37 = 7^{(7^7)} \neq (7^7)^{^7}$. So either this isn't a tetration or your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$7^{2004}=\big(7^2\big)^{1002}=49^{1002}\equiv1^{1002}=1\pmod 4$

As $\phi(10)=4$,

$7^{7^{2004}}\equiv7^1=7\pmod{10}$

Your solution is correct.

Comment: Doesn't this rely on $b \equiv c \mod n \to a^b \equiv a^c \mod n$? Because that doesn't hold: let $a = 2, b = 1, c = 4, n = 3$.

Comment: @StephenDonovan No, it relies on $b\equiv c\pmod{\phi(n)}\Rightarrow a^b\equiv a^c\pmod n$ for all $a$ coprime with $n$.

Comment: @StephenDonovan It should be $b\equiv c\pmod{\phi(n)}\rightarrow a^b\equiv a^c \pmod n$ with $a$ coprime with $n$

Comment: Ohh understood. My apologies, I missed that.

Answer (score 2):

If this is indeed a tetration, rather than a repeated taking the seventh power, the answer is different.

Tetration: $7^{\large 7^{\large 7^{\dots}}}$

Repeated power: $((7^7)^7)^7\cdots$

For tetration, the modulus of even a short tower of exponents rapidly settles down to a single value, unaffected by extending the tower, under the influence of the reducing cycles of higher exponents.

Here $7^k \equiv 7^\ell \bmod 10$ when $k \equiv \ell \bmod 4$ since $\lambda(10) = 4$

Then $7^{7^m} \equiv 7^{3^m} \equiv 7^{-1^m} \bmod 10$, directly giving a $2$-cycle, and since we can see that in the given case (of tetration) that $m$ is odd, we have

$$ 7^{\large 7^{\large 7^{\large 7^{\dots}}}} \equiv 7^{\large 7^{\text{[odd #]}}} \equiv 7^{-1} \equiv 3 \bmod 10$$

Comment: how can we show that " the modulus of even a short tower of exponents rapidly settles down to a single value, unaffected by extending the tower, under the influence of the reducing cycles of higher exponents".What is the reason behind it?.

Comment: Moreover , what if the modulus were odd instead of even, what would happen ?

Comment: @Bulbasaur - I mention this as an interesting effect in [this old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2050663) which mentions in a comment that this is due to the rapid descent of iterating the [Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function). It doesn't matter that much if the values involved are odd or even.

Comment: ,thank you very much ,it taught me new information..have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is right because I turned up with the same one with this approach:

$7^2\equiv -1\ \left(\text{mod}10\right)$ (Here -1 corresponds to 9)

$7^6\equiv \left(-1\right)^3=-1\ \left(\text{mod}10\right)$

$7^7\equiv 3\ \left(\text{mod}10\right)$

i.e.$7^7\equiv -7\ \left(\text{mod}10\right)$

similarly continuing, we get

$7^{7^7}\equiv \left(-7\right)^7\equiv \left(-7\right)\cdot \left(-7\right)^6\equiv -7\cdot \left(7\right)^6\equiv -7\cdot -1\equiv 7\ \left(\text{mod}10\right)$
and as 2004 is a multiple of 7, all will get cancelled to leave the remainder of 7.

Hence  the last digit is 7.